# POSTing a complex Dictionary to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, nancy

I am attempting to post the following type to my controller.

**Model**

```
public class EmailNotificationSettings
{
    public string EmailHost { get; set; }
    public string EmailPassword { get; set; }
    public int EmailPort { get; set; }
    public string EmailSender { get; set; }
    public string EmailUsername { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public bool EnableUserEmailNotifications { get; set; }
    public string RecipientEmail { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<NotificationType, NotificationMessageContent> Message { get; set; }
}
```

**NotificationType**

```
public enum NotificationType
{
    NewRequest,
    Issue,
    RequestAvailable,
    RequestApproved,
    AdminNote,
    Test,
}
```

**NotificationMessageContent**

```
public class NotificationMessageContent
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

Now all of the properties are part of my form except `Message`.
Here is how I plan to populate `Message`

**View**

```
<label for="newRequestSubject" class="control-label">New Request Subject</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-custom " id="newRequestSubject" name="newRequestSubject" value="@Model.Message.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == NotificationType.NewRequest).Value.Subject">
</div>

<label for="newRequestBody" class="control-label">New Request Body</label>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-custom " id="newRequestBody" name="newRequestBody" value="@Model.Message.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == NotificationType.NewRequest).Value.Body">
</div>
```

**Javascript to Post**

```
 $('#save').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var newRequestObj = {
            "Subject": $('#newRequestSubject').val(),
            "Body": $('#newRequestBody').val()
        };
        var message = { 'NewRequest': JSON.stringify(newRequestObj) };

        var $form = $("#mainForm");
        var data = $form.serialize();

        data = data + "&" +JSON.stringify(message);

        $.ajax({
            type: $form.prop("method"),
            data: data,
            url: $form.prop("action"),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
               // Do something
            }
        });
    });
```

Now this is obviously the wrong way to do it as my `Message` property is not getting populated.

Any idea how I can POST to the controller and it update my model?

**Controller if you want to see (Using NancyFX)**

```
private Response SaveEmailNotifications()
{
    var settings = this.Bind<EmailNotificationSettings>();
    // settings.Message doesn't contain the new values
}
```

Comment: While its possible (you need to generate form elements for the `Key` and `Value` properties of the `Dictionary` (refer [this article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx)), you will find this far easier is you use view models with `IList` or `IEnumerable` properties. And always use the strongly typed `HtmlHelper` methods to generate your form controls. Your currently generating name attributes that have no relationship at all to your model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes I understand my problem that the html has no relationship to my model. Do you have an example of a `HtmlHelper` to do this? Or Point me in the right direction?

Comment: It seems your only using `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first item in the Dictionary, so its unclear why you need a Dictionary? Based on the code you have shown all your view model needs is `public NotificationType NotificationType { get; set; }` and `public NotificationMessageContent NotificationMessageContent { get; set; }` and then just `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NotificationType)` and `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NotificationMessageContent.Subject)` and `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NotificationMessageContent.Body)` (and everything will be serialized using `var data = $form.serialize();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Ah apologies for the misunderstanding. The `FirstOrDefault()` was just me trying to get something working, the Dictionary contains 5 items (And only ever 5 items), each item will have it's own part in the form, That's why it's not really suitable to split it into two properties

Comment: Then you need to view models. It will be say `class Notification` with properties `NotificationType Type`, string Subject, and `string Body` and then `EmailNotificationSettings` contains property `List<Notification> Messages` and you use a `for` loop to generate the form controls.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a way to make it work with pure HTML. The problem is you need to submit a control with the name "Message" that contain the data, then MVC mapping engine will map that control to the "Message" property of your model.

The best way I can think of is to use a JavaScript function (bound to the `onsubmit` event of the form) which collects the info as an array of objects and assign it to a variable called "Message" then serialize it with the rest of the form data and submit the form.